# Meaning of different values put out in console for *p1 and p when dealing with pointers

Tags: c++

I'm a newbie to C++ and self teaching through online tuts. 
Today I was playing around with pointers and different results and just needed confirmation on something. I know how pointers work, basically. 
In the pics below are the simple code and the outputs in the console.

From what I understand the second value, 2, is the value stored in the element pointed by pointer p1 since output was for *p1 using the dereference operator(*).

The first value, 0x22ff1c, I just need confirmation on. I assume it is the value of the address in memory of the element since the output was for p1 which of course points to the address of a[1] using the reference operator/ampersand sign(&).

I'm quite sure I am right from what I have researched from on the net, but just needed someone to confirm it for me directly.

So my question is basically:
Is the 0x22ff1c indeed the address of the second element, and if not, what is that "funny looking" value then?

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
   int a[5] = {1,2,3,4,5};
   int *p1;
   p1 = &a[1];
   std::cout << "Value1: " << p1 << "\n" << "Value2: " << *p1;
   return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Value1: 0x22ff1c
Value2: 2
```

Comment: "In the pics below..." - please don't do that. Each time someone posts pictures of code on SO a kitten dies.

Comment: @WhozCraig Oh alright. It's just at the moment it's the only way that I know of to show what I have done to everyone. I thought that was what the pictures tab was there for. My mistake :/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, you're 100% right. It's the memory address of the second variable in the array.

---

Thorough explanation:

- `int *p1` declares `p1` as a pointer to an `int`.
- Pointers store memory addresses.
- `int *p1` stores the memory address of an `int` variable.
- `a[1]` accesses the second element in array `a`.
- `&a[1]` gives the memory address of that element.
- `p1 = &a[1]` assigns that memory address to `p1`.
- `p1` is a memory address so outputting that will output the address.
- `*p1` accesses whatever is at the memory address `p1`.
- There's an `int` at that memory address so outputting `*p1` will output that `int`.

Comment: Indeed a thorough explanation. Excellent! Thanks, Zenith. :)

Answer (score 3):

You understood it right, it is the address and addresses are traditionally written in hexadecimal notation.

Comment: Oh okay. So the hexadecimal notation explains why it looks so "funny". Thanks for pointing that out to me, Marco. :)

Answer (score 2):

Pointers are variables like any other, but their value is the adress of the variable which they are pointing to.

In your case:

```
int a[5] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
int *p1;
p1 = &a[1];

cout << *p1 << "\n"; // dereferencing the pointer (prints 2)
cout << p1 << "\n";  // printing value of pointer (prints adress)
```

Dereferencing the pointer (`*` operator) gives you the value the pointer points to, which is the 2nd value in the `int a[5]` array.

Passing the pointer into cout gives you the value of the pointer (adress of `a[1]`) which is printed in hexadecimal format.

**Bonus:**

```
cout << &p1 << "\n"; // prints adress of pointer
```

Passing the adress (`&` operator) of a pointer to cout prints the adress of the pointer (a pointer is a variable like any other). This (`&p1`) is different from `p1`.

Comment: Ahhh... Thanks for that bonus tip there. Much appreciated :)